# Links do not work after Wordpress migration

Tags: wordpress

I made a copy of my website http://www.healthclubone.nl to http://www.healthclubone.nl/test/

The problem is that the links (voetbal, fitness, etc) direct to the original website. I did the following to fix this:

1) Edit wp-config adding the following:
define( 'WP_SITEURL', '' );
define( 'WP_HOME', '' );

2) search and replace pluging to edit database

3) edit settings in admin (wordpress address and site address)

If I look in the source code the links () seem to be correct.

Any thoughts on this are welcome.
Thank you!

Comment: what links are they? Were they inserted in static form?

Comment: Hi David, the problem is with the links in the menu/buttons. For example: http://healthclubone.nl/test/fitness/ goes to http://healthclubone.nl/fitness/ They were created by the wordpress dashboard (create page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you another way.

1) Use http://test.healthclubone.nl instead the http://www.healthclubone.nl/test/ ... wordpress can be confused (e.g. if where is a site called "test")

2) Fresh start!

2.1 Install a new WordPress

2.2 copy the "content"-directory

2.3 Use this plugin in to migrate the database
https://github.com/wp-sync-db/wp-sync-db

2.4 Done and happy :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the voetbal, fitness, etc. links you were talking about but if they are from the WordPress Menus, you may have your menus using "custom link" and not the posts/pages/categories type.

To confirm that this is not the case, go to: Appearance -> Menus

Click the down arrow beside each menu item and make sure there isn't a custom link in them. If they are using a custom link that's pointing to the original site, you can correct it or delete it and select a menu of the pages/posts/categories type, directly from the left pane then drag into the menu.

Don't forget to click Save Menu button to save the changes when you're done. Refresh the page and try again.

see: https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide for more